# Material UI unable to import and using ClickAwayListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, onclicklistener

I am using material-ui for my project and doing the password-changing functionality, this is my root file where I import children components:

**Personalize.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { CurrentUserContext } from '../providers/CurrentUserContextProvider';

import Header from '../component/Header';
import Sidebar from '../component/Sidebar';
import ChangeProfileImage from '../component/Main/PersonalizeMain/ChangeProfileImage';
import ChangePassword from '../component/Main/PersonalizeMain/ChangePassword';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
    },
    toolbar: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
        marginTop: '65px',
        // necessary for content to be below app bar
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    },
    content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },
}));

const Personalize = ({ history, location, match }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const token = cookies.get('token');

    if (token === undefined) {
        history.push('/login');
    }

    const { currentUser } = useContext(CurrentUserContext);
    const { profileImage } = currentUser;
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleDrawerClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Header open={open} handleDrawerOpen={handleDrawerOpen} />
            <Sidebar open={open} handleDrawerClose={handleDrawerClose} />
            <main className={classes.content}>
                <div className={classes.toolbar}>
                    <Grid container justify="space-evenly" alignItems="center">
                        <Grid item>
                            <ChangeProfileImage profileImage={profileImage} />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item>
                            <ChangePassword />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    );
};

export default withRouter(Personalize);
```

As you can see I import a child component called `ChangePassword`, here is the code.

**ChangePassword.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { IconButton, TextField, Grid, Snackbar, ClickAwayListener } from '@material-ui/core';

import MuiAlert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';

import VisibilityIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Visibility';
import VisibilityOffIcon from '@material-ui/icons/VisibilityOff';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const Alert = (props) => {
    return <MuiAlert elevation={6} variant="filled" {...props} />;
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    MuiInputBaseInput: {
        '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
            minWidth: '300px',
        },
    },
    customePositionIconButton: { position: 'relative', top: '-50px', right: '-130px' },
}));

const ChangePassword = ({ history, location, match }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [passwordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(false);
    const [confirmPasswordVisible, setConfirmPasswordVisible] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const [password, setPassword] = useState({
        newPass: '',
        confirmPass: '',
    });

    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const token = cookies.get('token');

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        var charCode = typeof event.which == 'number' ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        var { newPass, confirmPass } = password;
        if (charCode === 13) {
            if (confirmPass === '' || password === '') {
                return setError('Emptied Password');
            }

            if (newPass.trim() === confirmPass.trim()) {
                fetch('http://localhost:5000/users/me', {
                    method: 'PATCH',
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer '.concat(token),
                        'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ newPass }),
                })
                    .then((response) => {
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then((json) => {
                        var { doc } = json;
                        if (doc) {
                            setOpen(true);
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            } else {
                setError('Passwords Not Matched');
            }
        }
    };

    const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
        if (reason === 'clickaway') {
            return;
        }

        setOpen(false);
    };

    const handleClickAway = () => {
        setError('');
    };

    return (
        <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <Grid container direction="column" justify="center" alignItems="center">
                    <Grid item className={classes.MuiInputBaseInput}>
                        <TextField
                            type={passwordVisible ? 'text' : 'password'}
                            variant="outlined"
                            label="New Password"
                            required
                            onChange={(event) => {
                                setError('');
                                setPassword({ ...password, newPass: event.target.value });
                            }}
                            onKeyDown={handleSubmit}
                            error={error === '' ? false : true}
                            helperText={error}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item>
                        <IconButton
                            className={classes.customePositionIconButton}
                            onClick={() => {
                                setPasswordVisible(!passwordVisible);
                            }}
                        >
                            {passwordVisible ? <VisibilityOffIcon /> : <VisibilityIcon />}
                        </IconButton>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item className={classes.MuiInputBaseInput}>
                        <TextField
                            type={confirmPasswordVisible ? 'text' : 'password'}
                            variant="outlined"
                            label="Confirm Password"
                            required
                            onChange={(event) => {
                                setError('');
                                setPassword({ ...password, confirmPass: event.target.value });
                            }}
                            onKeyDown={handleSubmit}
                            error={error === '' ? false : true}
                            helperText={error}
                        />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item>
                        <IconButton
                            className={classes.customePositionIconButton}
                            onClick={() => {
                                setConfirmPasswordVisible(!confirmPasswordVisible);
                            }}
                        >
                            {confirmPasswordVisible ? <VisibilityOffIcon /> : <VisibilityIcon />}
                        </IconButton>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </form>
            <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
                <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success">
                    Password successfully changed
                </Alert>
            </Snackbar>
        </ClickAwayListener>
    );
};

export default withRouter(ChangePassword);
```

I have imported `ClickAwayListener` to `setError` to an emptied string, but I got this error and I can not understand why. I've already double checked and find no cause.

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
> component from the file it's defined in, or you may have mixed up default and
> named imports

[image: img]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ClickAwayListener`](https://material-ui.com/components/click-away-listener/) only accepts one child component, not array of components. So in your code, change this

```js
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
  <form>
    {...}
  </form>
  <Snackbar />
</ClickAwayListener>
```

To this

```js
<>
  <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
    <form>
      {...}
    </form>
  </ClickAwayListener>
  <Snackbar />
</>
```

And it will work again.